# DNS problem in Google Chrome (in Debian/Linux)

Tags: google-chrome, dns

My hostname is `abc.my-company.com`, and there is `www.m.com.my-company.com` in the domain.

The domain name `my-company.com` should be added to `www.m.com`. While this works very well with `Firefox`, `links`, `wget`, etc.  But I found that `Chrome` doesn't support this.  For example, `http://www.s.com/` couldn't be opened. I guess Chrome has its own resolve algorithm, there may be some options to disable it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the fix described in:

[Turn off DNS pre-fetching in Google Chrome to fix page loading problems](http://jackkonblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/turn-off-dns-pre-fetching-in-google.html).

Comment: I found that the problem is caused by `SwitchyProxy` extension. Thanks .